# Replacing character string with another character string

Tags: r, gsub

I have a data frame for which I am attempting to replace certain values with others. So, as a small example, I have a dummy data frame of:

```
dummy<-c("1","2","3","4")
dummy<-data.frame(dummy)
dummy$dummy<-as.character(dummy$dummy)

odd<-c("1","3")

replace(dummy$dummy, dummy$dummy==odd, "odd")

#> [1] "odd" "2"   "3"   "4"
```

Why would this only replace "1" with "odd" and not "3"?

My actual dataset has more information in it (it is restaurant cuisine types and I need to replace the types of cuisine by a more general category. For example, I have the cuisine types "Italian" and "French" in my dataset that need to be replaced with "European", and cuisine types "Southwestern" and "Pacific Northwestern" that need to be replaced with "American".

Is the above idea the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Look at library stringr for a set of robust string methods, In your case str_replace in stringr, or gsub in base R

Comment: @epi99

I tried gsub with the following code and error message:

`code`
> dummy<-c("1","2","3","4")
> dummy<-data.frame(dummy)
> dummy$dummy<-as.character(dummy$dummy)
> gsub(odd,"odd",dummy$dummy)
[1] "odd" "2"   "3"   "4" 

Warning message:
In gsub(odd, "odd", dummy$dummy) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: No, it's not the most efficient method.  I would recommend you begin with integers and add a column to denote the odd values `dummy$odd <- dummy$dummy %% 2 != 0`.  Mixing numerics and characters is never a good idea.

Comment: While the answers below will do what you're asking, I'd second what @Rich Scriven suggests above. You can test for oddness in the usual way, which is much more logical than testing for string matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [epi99](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4357329/epi99) suggested, you can use [`stringr::str_replace()`](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html) for this. You might also want to look over their guide to using [Regular Expressions](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html) as well.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data_frame(dummy = c("1","2","3","4"))

df %>% mutate(dummy = str_replace(dummy, "1|3", "odd"))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   dummy
#>   <chr>
#> 1   odd
#> 2     2
#> 3   odd
#> 4     4
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your replacement is an actual variable; if so, you can replace with an `ifelse` statement as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(dummy = c("1","2","3","4"))
df$dummy <- ifelse(df$dummy %in% c(1,3), "Odd", df$dummy)
df

  dummy
1   Odd
2     2
3   Odd
4     4
```

Comment: Also, you can fix your replace statement borrowing from the syntax in my answer with the `%in%`.    `replace(dummy$dummy, dummy$dummy %in% odd, "odd")`

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R`

```
levels(df$dummy)[levels(df$dummy) %in% c(1, 3)] <- "odd"
df
#  dummy
#1   odd
#2     2
#3   odd
#4     4
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(dummy = c("1","2","3","4"))
```